# Python if then statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function called `isNeg` which will take a single parameter `myList`,a list of integers, and will return `True` if `myList` consists of entirely negative integers or return "False" otherwise. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) or [`all`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function like this

```
def isNeg(input_list):
    return all(current_number < 0 for current_number in input_list)
```

You can use `any` function, like this

```
def isNeg(input_list):
    return not any(current_number >= 0 for current_number in input_list)
```

**Sample Runs:**

```
print(isNeg([1, 2, 3, 4]))       # False
print(isNeg([-1, -2, -3, -4]))   # True
print(isNeg([-1, 2, -3, -4]))    # False
```